# Diffraction grating and light source intensity

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, spectroscopy, diffraction

In an absorption spectroscopy, light sources are often XENON or deuterium + halogen lamp, which tend to have wide spectrum (example: 180-700). Consider cases, where no slit or optical filter is applied, as this is case for recent usb spectrometer.

Example: https ://i.stack.imgur.com/M0avz.png

[image]

In these cases, the incident light's intensity is a function of wavelength.

What I don't understand is following. Say incident light `Io(y)` passes through the sample, now the intensity of the light has changed based on wavelength. It is now `Ia(y)`.

[image]

If we use diffraction grating on this incident light, in essence, the light with different wavelength will spread apart and will hit different parts of a linear sensor. When this occurs, is the intensity of the light kept proportional to each other?

What I mean to understand is, when we use a diffraction grating, the intensity of absorbed light, does it change proportionally. For example, if at 300nm say we had highest absorption `-log(Io(y)/I(y))`, and at 200nm lowest absorption, is the ratio between them kept approximately same? If so, if my light source was only 300-320 nm, I should always expect low-intensity readings from my sensor for every other range?

Thanks :)